# Loop variable error in for loop

Tags: scripts

When I’m using for like

```
 for i in 1 2 3 4 5
```

then my file contains `#!/bin/sh` at the top.

But when I’m using

```
for(( i = 0; i<=5; i++))
```

then it is showing error

```
Syntax error: Bad for loop variable
```

and running properly when I remove shebang. Please tell me the reason behind this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`for(( i = 0; i<=5; i++))` is Bash specific and doesn't work with plain Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`).

If you remove the shebang the script is run by your current shell (which likely is Bash) so it works.

Replace `#!/bin/sh` with `#!/bin/bash` to make the shebang work.

Comment: Is there any way to do it in `sh` mode? Thanks!

Comment: `i=0; while [ $i -le 5 ]; do echo $i; i=$((i+1)); done`

Comment: I use #bash already and not works

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this problem by using ./ instead of sh command.
For an example if you put `sh test.sh` instead just make your command as `./test.sh` And most probably problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(( i = 0; i<=5; i++))
```

for this type of loop only runs on Bash shell. so, if you want to run this, then try this command :

```
$bash filename.sh
```

I think It will work fine. and see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash) also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out may be this could solve your problem

```
#!/bin/bash
j=0
for (( i=1; i <= 5; i++ ))
do
 echo "the loop is runing $i time: and value of j is $j"
 j=`expr $j + 1`
done
```